# Sharepoint update email on a specific date

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

Hi using SharePoint 2013, I need the owners of list items in an open state to receive an email on the 10th month requesting an update.

This needs to continue until the item is in a closed state.

Can't think of a neat way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a scheduled workflow or utility which runs daily to check

Get item with open state

Loop through each item

check diffrence between  item created/updated date and today's date is more than 10 months(if I understood correctly)

If so send email

If not process next item.

Above logic would be same if you are creating scheduled workflow with frequency to run daily or schedule utility(based on CSOM) Utility can scheduled to run daily as windows task schedulerr